# Ĉu oni "ludas" kiam oni alklakas la butonon?

Tags: verbs

En la angla oni diras "play" pri la butono kun triangulo(▶️). Ankaŭ la verbo estas "to play" kiam oni alklakas ĝin kaj ekigas la filmon aŭ kanton. Kiun verbon mi uzu esperante? Sentus al mi strange diri "ludi muzikon" se mi ne uzas instrumenton, nur metas KDn en stereomaŝino aŭ telefonon en aŭskultilo.

Answer (score 9):

La ĝusta esprimo en ĉi tiu kunteksto estas ***ludigi***, ĉar oni **igas** la aparaton **ludi** la muzikon.

Comment: Mi ecx pridubis cxu la aparato "ludas" la muzikon. Kio pri filmoj? Cxu ili ankaux estas "ludataj" de aparatoj?

Comment: @Antonia Montaro: Laŭ [Bertilo](http://bertilow.com/piv/): _Nuntempe ekzistas similaj aŭtomatoj, kiuj ludigas videajn filmdiskojn_.

Comment: En la retejo de Bertilo troviĝas kelkaj frazoj kun tia senco de _ludig-_, ekz.: _diskestro --> persono, kiu prizorgas la [ludigon](http://bertilow.com/roko/cd.html) de diskoj (aŭ kasedoj k.t.p.) en diskoteko, radielsendo aŭ simile; por [ludigi](http://bertilow.com/roko/k.html) k-diskon oni uzas kompaktadiskludilon_. Laŭ PIV [diskaŭtomato](http://vortaro.net/#diska%C5%ADtomato) estas aŭtomato, kiu elektas kaj ludas muzikajn diskojn, kiam monero estas enŝovita en ĝin.

Answer (score 3):

Miaimprese oni tamen uzas la verbon *ludi* en tiaj situacioj. Sed vi pravas, ke tio ne estas la tipa uzo de la verbo rilate muzikon, ĉar la subjekto nek mem uzas muzikilon (signifo 4 en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ludi)) nek aŭdigas muzikon per muzikilo (signifo 5). Sed la signifo estas tre proksima, kaj se vi imagas la butonon kiel ordonon al la aparato "ludu", tiam ja temas pri la ĝusta signifo.

Alternative/Aldone, ĉar ja estas la aparato, kiu ludas la muzikon, vi povas pri vi mem diri, ke vi *lud**ig**as* la muzikon.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus *vidigi* (filmojn) aux *sxalti* (muzikilon).  Oni ankaux povas diri *komenci* aux ecx "ekigi".

Comment: Mi pensas, ke _vidigi_ ne taŭgas por filmoj, ĉar la sonoj de la filmo estas same gravaj. Aliflanke, _spektigi_ ne vere taŭgas, ĉar oni povas simple ne spekti la filmon, kiun oni alklakis.

Comment: Jes, mi scias, ke oni povas auxskulti la sonon de filmoj; tamen, mi ankoraux pensas ke vidigi tauxgas, cxefe cxar, aux angle aux esperante, kiam oni parolas pri filmoj, la vida aspekto pligravas.  Oni kutime diras "spekti" aux "vidi" aux "rigardi" filmojn.

Comment: Mi ne samopinias. La vorto _spekti_ entenas kaj la bildojn kaj la sonojn. Sonas al mi strange diri en Esperanto, ke oni ‘rigardas’ aŭ ‘vidas’ filmon; oni _spektas_ filmon. La difino de _spekti_ el PIV: “Atenti per la vido k aŭdo tion, kio estas prezentata”. Ke io estas uzata en iu lingvo laŭ mi ne vere estas bona argumento por uzi tion en Esperanto. (Tiu argumento ja povas esti uzata por klarigi la originon de iu uzo en Esperanto.)

Comment: Bone, Joffy, Interesas ke _spekti_ inkluzivas kaj la auxdan kaj la vidan aspekton, sed verdire, nun ni estas engagxitaj en harfendado, cxu ne?  Mi jam trafis kelfoje ekzemplojn de la dirmaniero _vidi la filmon_, do mi scias ke tio uzigxas.   Kiam oni spektas la televidilon, kion ni diras?  Ni diras ke oni "televidas", cxu ne?  La situacio estas sama--oni teleVIDAS, kaj oni ankaux povas VIDI filmojn.

Comment: Vi pravas, ke homoj diras _rigardi_ aŭ _vidi_ filmon; tiam ili estas aŭ malpli precizaj, aŭ la aŭskultado aŭ aŭdado estas subkomprenata. Pro tio _spekti_ estas laŭ mi preferinda. Koncerne _televidi_, tio verŝajne estas tia ne tiom pro logiko, kiom pro la deveno de internacia vorto.

Comment: Mi havas la impreson ke _vidigi_ estas pli proksima al la senco _to make or let someone see something, to show_, ol al _to play (a film) for someone_, ekzemple: _multjara praktikado vidigis al li gravan maltaŭgecon_ (Tekstaro). Ankaŭ vortaroj montras tion: _Lasi aŭ igi iun vidi; montri; fari vidata_.

Answer (score 0):

**Ludi** estas (malgraŭ ĉio) ĝusta kaj adekvata. Ludante muzikon ĉu kiel muzikisto, ĉu kiel programo, "music player", estas formo de ***reproduktado***. Vidu [Komputeko] (http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=play) (je la fino) ankaŭ por iuj alternativoj.

Pluraj naciaj lingvoj uzas la saman verbon. Tamen kelkaj lingvoj uzas alian verbon distingante inter ludado de infanoj (distraĵo) kaj ludado de muziko (spertaĵo, la nocio ĉi tie).

*Playing a movie*, aŭ *movie player*, laŭ mi estas la sama reprodukta afero. Kaj oni ne nepre bezonas "precizigi" per **legilo**.

En [Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/):

> 3) Prezenti spektaĵon, vivan artaĵon.